# When I try to get quote shipping address, it returns customer default address. Does the quote session not updated with value in the table?

Tags: magento2.2, checkoutsession

When I try to get quote shipping address, it returns customer default address instead of returning from my quote_address table.

I'm trying to pre-populate checkout fields with quote address details. So trying to get `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()`  When I put `getData()` it gives all the values from `quote_address` tables but the address details like firstname, lastname, street are different from table data. 
This details fetched from customer default shipping address. Anybody facing this kind of issue?